# Several Tor sessions when using several Tor processes

Tags: relays, ubuntu

I want use several different Tor configurations (different countries) on Ubuntu server.
I found this one, however, i get some errors.

```
root@s2hptor:~# /usr/sbin/tor -f /usr/local/etc/torrc1
Apr 19 22:51:52.005 [notice] Tor v0.2.4.20 (git-0d50b03673670de6) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable and OpenSSL 1.0.1f.
Apr 19 22:51:52.006 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Apr 19 22:51:52.006 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/local/etc/torrc1".
Apr 19 22:51:52.018 [warn] ControlPort is open, but no authentication method has been configured.  This means that any program on your computer can reconfigure your Tor.  That's bad!  You should upgrade your Tor controller as soon as possible.
Apr 19 22:51:52.020 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Apr 19 22:51:52.020 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9061
Apr 19 22:51:52.020 [notice] Opening OR listener on 1.0.1.16:9001
Apr 19 22:51:52.020 [warn] Could not bind to 1.0.1.16:9001: Cannot assign requested address
Apr 19 22:51:52.020 [notice] Opening Directory listener on 1.0.1.16:9031
Apr 19 22:51:52.020 [warn] Could not bind to 1.0.1.16:9031: Cannot assign requested address
Apr 19 22:51:52.021 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Apr 19 22:51:52.021 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9061
Apr 19 22:51:52.021 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Apr 19 22:51:52.021 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

I tried turn off firewall but it did not help.

Also, can i use one single IP and different ports (on one ubuntu server) or i have to use different IPs and different ports?

Comment: What do you mean by »different countries«?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can't run more than one program on a single port. Once a program starts it uses a port and the operating system blocks it for other programs. So when you want to run different Tor processes, you'll need a different set of ports for each process. In your configuration `DirPort`, `ORPort`, `SocksPort` and `ControlPort` was set. If you really need all four ports, every `torrc` should contain different ones.

Generally you should check if you really need all those ports for your Tor process. According to the [FAQ](https://www.torservers.net/wiki/faq) entry you'll need `ORPort` and `DirPort` ([Which ports should I use?](https://www.torservers.net/wiki/faq#which_ports_should_i_use)). The site also has some information for running [multiple Tor processes](https://www.torservers.net/wiki/setup/server#multiple_tor_processes).